# Mysql stored procedure If condition doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, procedure

I have a mysql stored procedure to check if the login information matchs with my database information

obs:I've just started using Mysql, so it may have a lot of errors in this code.

-Table 1 - Funcionario (email_func,senha)

-Table 2 - Cliente (email_cli,senha_cli)

Here's the sp code

```
delimiter %%
create procedure SpLogin(email varchar(100), senha varchar(15))
begin
declare c int;
declare f int;
begin
 if exists(select * from cliente where email_cli = email and senha_cli = md5(senha))
 then select 'c' as result;
 else set c = 0;
end if;
end;
begin
 if  exists (select * from funcionario where email_func = email and senha = senha)
 then select 'f' as result;
 else set f = 0; 
end if;
end;
begin
 if  (f = 0 and c = 0)
 then select '0' as result;
 end if;
 end;
end %%
delimiter ;
```

There is an 'email' that is the same in the two tables, when I call the sp with this email
It always return 'f' as result regardless what 'senha' I write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should name your procedure parameters with a different name than the column names in your table.

```
where ... senha = senha
```

The column `senha` is bound to be equal to the column `senha` in the same row.

MySQL doesn't know that you mean the first `senha` is the column, and the second `senha` is the procedure parameter.

Comment: Thank you, it worked